# Import .key presentations from Keynote

Tags: software-recommendation, file-format

Is there a way to import .key files from Keynote into OpenOffice in Ubuntu?

I know you can open them as zip files, but can't I open them as PDF or something similar?

Comment: can you export them in osx?

Comment: Thanks, I am downloading the presentation from Slideshare, so I can't

Comment: Related question: http://superuser.com/questions/154481/how-to-open-mac-keynote-presentations-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this [is not possible](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=4706). If you have access to Keynote then you can export as `.ppt` and then import this file into OpenOffice Impress.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem with Slideshare all the time.

I just found [zamzar.com](http://zamzar.com). They have online conversion or email conversion. To convert `something.foo` to `something.bar` attach the source file to an email to `bar@zamzar.com` where `bar` is the desired output format.

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible, but it requires creating an iCloud account.  Once the account is created, click on the Keynote icon, then click on the gear icon and select "Upload Presentation..."

Once that is done, an icon should appear along with the title of the presentation.  Click on it, and it should open up the presentation in a web view.  Clicking on the wrench icon and selecting "Download a Copy..." should give you the option of downloading the file as a Keynote, PDF, or PowerPoint file.